# Cannot get / Error in MEAN stack application

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I'm following the tutorial of Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api
I followed every step without the deployment to Heroku server and worked in my localhost.
So when I open my application with the port localhost/8080 I found the error of (Cannot Get / ).
this is my server code :

```html
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;

var CONTACTS_COLLECTION = "contacts";

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Create link to Angular build directory
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
app.use(express.static(distDir));

// Create a database variable outside of the database connection callback to reuse the connection pool in your app.
var db;

// Connect to the database before starting the application server.
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/test", { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
  db = client.db();
  console.log("Database connection ready");

  // Initialize the app.
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });
});

// CONTACTS API ROUTES BELOW

// Generic error handler used by all endpoints.
function handleError(res, reason, message, code) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
  res.status(code || 500).json({"error": message});
}

/*  "/api/contacts"
 *    GET: finds all contacts
 *    POST: creates a new contact
 */

app.get("/api/contacts", function(req, res) {
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get contacts.");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(docs);
    }
  });
});



app.post("/api/contacts", function(req, res) {
  var newContact = req.body;
  newContact.createDate = new Date();

  if (!req.body.name) {
    handleError(res, "Invalid user input", "Must provide a name.", 400);
  } else {
    db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).insertOne(newContact, function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new contact.");
      } else {
        res.status(201).json(doc.ops[0]);
      }
    });
  }
});

/*  "/api/contacts/:id"
 *    GET: find contact by id
 *    PUT: update contact by id
 *    DELETE: deletes contact by id
 */

app.get("/api/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get contact");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(doc);
    }
  });
});

app.put("/api/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
  var updateDoc = req.body;
  delete updateDoc._id;

  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, updateDoc, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to update contact");
    } else {
      updateDoc._id = req.params.id;
      res.status(200).json(updateDoc);
    }
  });
});

app.delete("/api/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).deleteOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to delete contact");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(req.params.id);
    }
  });
});
```

PS: when I run the command ng serve: the main page shows but no connection with the database it's just a static page .. please help
and I'm a beginner in this mean languages.

Comment: You do not have any route matching to `/`.

Comment: I know i want to add my home route to the page that shows when i run the ommand ng serve but i didn't knew how

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it misses a part in your server code.
You have configured your API part, which can be called by your Angular app, but you're not serving your Angular app.

You should listen to all GET request and send as only file your `index.html` which in fact should contain your Angular SPA.
Something like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));    
});
```

You can have a look at the Express doc: http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: and how my friedn , i'm totally beginner i should prepare this work for presentation after tomorow :/